# How to specify multiple appsettings files in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, appsettings

I would like to know if it is possible to specify multiple `appsettings` files within the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable - which is located in `launchSettings.json` file? Essentially, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": ["Development", "AddOn"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The environment can only have a single value. I think you might want to add a JSON file to the configuration builder so you get the addon one in addition to the default?

Comment: Please have a look at [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0).